# is it possible to generate an SSL certificate for an internal site?

Tags: ssl

On Windows10 I have an internal website on iis, which I access through a url https://localhost:44300.

Currently I have the security messages come up when I first load the url and I have the broken padlock.

Unfortunately the network I'm on blocks security certificate warnings and I can't get to my site.

Is it possible to buy an SSL certificate for an internal site?

At the moment I'm using mkcert to be my own CA, but I'm told this is not suitable for a production site.

Thanks Ian.

Comment: *"I'm told this is not suitable for a production site"* What is your goal? Is this a web application that will be deployed to customer machines (and run on "their" localhost), or do you just need the internal website for development?

Comment: Depending on what it is, this page nicely summarizes your options: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: It's a web app that will be on a Customers self hosted server and no internet connection.

Comment: I see. In that case, the most common solution I am aware of is to use a self-signed certificate, but to add it to the browser's certificate store to avoid the certificate security warnings. Alternatively, you could get an official certificate if you use a publicly accessible DNS name (only the DNS name needs to be public, not the IP), see, for example, this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103524/12244

Comment: I have tried making a self-signed cert in approx. 100 different ways via IIS and PowerShell and added the self-signed cert to every location possible, but the security message will not go away.  The only way I have found so far is to use mkcert.